# Python BeautifulSoup & Selenium not scraping full html

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Beginner web-scraper here. My practice task is simple: Collect/count a player's Pokemon usage over their last 50 games, [on this page for example](https://uniteapi.dev/p/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A1). To do this, I planned to use the image url of the Pokemon which contains the Pokemon's name (in an `<img>` tag, encased by `<span></span>`). Inspecting from Chrome ***looks like this***: `<img alt="Played pokemon" srcset="/_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Snorlax.png&amp;w=96&amp;q=75 1x, /_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Snorlax.png&amp;w=256&amp;q=75 2x" ...`

**1)** Using Beautiful Soup alone doesn't get the html of the images that I need:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://uniteapi.dev/p/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A1')
wp_player = bs(r.content)
wp_player.select('span img')
```

**2)** Using Selenium picks up some of what BeautifulSoup missed:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://uniteapi.dev/p/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A1"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
soup.select('span img')
```

But it gives me links that ***look like this***: `<img alt="Played pokemon" data-nimg="fixed" decoding="async" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"`

What am I misunderstanding here? The website I'm interested in does not have a public API, despite its name. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: headless browser - is it obligatory? is this a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue while web scraping websites before these gets loaded completely. What you'll have to do is basically wait for the page to fully load the images that you are requiring. You have two options, either [implicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits) or [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the image elements to get loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = r"https://uniteapi.dev/p/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A1"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[alt="Played pokemon"]'))) # EXPLICIT WAIT
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # IMPLICIT WAIT

pokemons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[alt="Played pokemon"]')
for element in pokemons:
    print(element.get_attribute("src"))
```

You have to choose one or the other, but it's better to explicit wait for the element(s) to get rendered before you try to access to their values.

> OUTPUT:
> pokemons =
> driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[alt="Played pokemon"]')
> https://uniteapi.dev/_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Tsareena.png&w=256&q=75
> https://uniteapi.dev/_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Tsareena.png&w=256&q=75
> https://uniteapi.dev/_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Snorlax.png&w=256&q=75
> https://uniteapi.dev/_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Snorlax.png&w=256&q=75
> https://uniteapi.dev/_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Snorlax.png&w=256&q=75
> https://uniteapi.dev/_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Snorlax.png&w=256&q=75
> https://uniteapi.dev/_next/image?url=%2FSprites%2Ft_Square_Snorlax.png&w=256&q=75

Your workaround wasn't working because you are doing a get request to the page that gets you the html values at their initial state, when all the DOM elements are still yet to get rendered.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your detailed response. I used your method, but I still get `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BA...`. Only on occasion do I get some of the correct links. It seems to me that `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located()` doesn't wait for the correct text in the attribute `src`. No matter how long I wait using `implicitly_wait()` or `time.sleep()`, it still gives me the unrendered links. Any ideas why it might work for you but not for me?

Comment: Hi, it's because the page isn't loading completely. I'd recommend you to implicit wait for the values, but if this is not working properly let's see how much time it's taking everything to load, for that comment the `headless` and `disable-gpu` arguments and run the script with the implicit wait, and check in the chrome tab if the page has fully loaded and the `src` values had changed when you're retrieving the values in the code.

Comment: Ah okay. It seems that the problem is that my chromedriver doesn't actually load the webpage in the background. I have to manually scroll through the whole page just to ensure that the images load. This is an entirely other problem that I'll have to sus out on my own. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that this site is using what is called Ajax to load the Pokémon dynamically via JavaScript.

One thing you can do is actually observe the network tab in the debugger and look for the url that contains the data, and if you can call the url directly that returns the data you are looking for.

A lot of times when web scraping, you can do this and it’ll return the data in a more serialized format.

Otherwise you can do as was mentioned in Sac’s answer and just wait for the data to fully load. Either by checking if an element has loaded yet, or just hard coding a sleep call, which is less clean.

Answer (score 0):

Although not an answer, we specifically put in anti scraping devices in our code. I would appreciate it if you did not try to scrape our website and had talked to us at our discord instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).